# Why is my iPhone still listed in iCloud though I erased all content and settings on the device?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I erased all content and settings on my iPhone, and the Find My iPhone activation lock was disabled (no activation lock). So ... Why is it still listed in iCloud Settings, Devices? The info blurb on Devices page says that it's listing the devices still signed in. How is this phone still signed in? Is this normal? Is something wrong?  It should be signed **out**. Maybe it could be listed as an old device ... but not "Signed In". I no longer have possession of this phone. I am very concerned for what this means. Worried I did something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-afri/HT201351), you should have signed out before deleting the device.  The article provides also alternative methods (in case one has no control of the device).

> 2. If you're using iCloud and Find My iPhone on the device, sign in to iCloud.com or the Find My iPhone app on another device, select the device, and click Erase. After the device has been erased, click Remove from Account.
> 3. If you can't follow either of the above steps, change your Apple ID password. This won't remove personal information that's stored on your old device, but it prevents the new owner from deleting your information from iCloud.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read the link and it also says:     "*When you tap Erase All Content and Settings, it completely erases your device, including any credit or debit cards you added for Apple Pay and any photos, contacts, music, or apps. It will also turn off iCloud, iMessage, FaceTime, Game Center, and other services. Your content won't be deleted from iCloud when you erase your device.
Published Date: Dec 15, 2016"              So .... erasing my phone should have turned off icloud. If icloud is turned off by erasing, how can it be listed under Devices as still "Signed In"?